# App is crashing when I am opening a basic activity

Tags: java, android

I recently started learning android,and I am using basic activity with a  button 'fab' as default given name.

here is my java file

```
   public class AddNewMember extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_member);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewMember.this, HomeScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

the fab button takes user directly to home screen. But the activity crashes saying the following lines

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.adt.alphadev.rotarydist3132, PID: 3361
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1380)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1368)
                                                 at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                 at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:464)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                 at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:476)
                                                 at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                 at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:669)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:89)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1319)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:734)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java
```

add new member activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_add_new_member" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_home_black_24dp" />
```

Home screen java file

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton btn_dashboard, btn_reporting,btn_apply_credits,btn_upload_bulletin,btn_view_rank;
ImageButton btn_add_new_member,btn_update_club_details,btn_view_projects,btn_view_members,btn_view_notifications,btn_change_password,btn_logout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
  btn_add_new_member = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_new_member);
  btn_add_new_member.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, AddNewMember.class));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 


  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: when you are in the onCreate method, you haven't yet inflated or constructed the View which the FAB is. You need to Override the onCreateView() method and reference the FAB there - at a minimum.

Comment: When your app crash after clicking on the fab button ??

Comment: show your layout file and also your HomeScreen's activity file

Comment: There's more code to the project than just that...

Comment: Can you show the code in HomeScreen.java? I think the crashing may come from there.

Comment: share the `AddNewMember` activity file, the error is not in the `onCreate` method

Comment: I am trying to copy paste the code but formatting is taking for ever... :P

Comment: now i have added xml of add new member

Comment: @thunder413 app crashes when i click on a button there which takes me to add new member activity. But instead if opening new activity, it crashes saying null pointer.

Comment: If that's your XML, then your issue is that your layout doesn't have a viewgroup root like `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: @walimbeakshay the crash happens in the `onCreate` method of HomeScreen. You're probably using `getVisibility()` on a null reference or before calling `setContentView()`. Show the code of HomeScreen so we can make sure

Comment: post the `onCreate()` method of **HomeScreen.java**

Comment: There is one more thing, its a basic activity not blank. So should i put my xml design elements in content_activity name or activity_name???

Comment: I don't get your question, whatever the name of the xml file it won't matter, and your problem here is in onCreate() method of the HomeScreen.java

Comment: Okay, @MuhammedRefaat I will post the home screen java code in a minute

Comment: Now i have added home screen java file code.

Comment: where you perform the `getVisibility()` check ?!! and to which view ?!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117617/discussion-between-walimbeakshay-and-muhammed-refaat).

Comment: I have not written getVisibility() any where or came across any such call in my prior examples. Can you please elaborate

Comment: @BraSaeed I have added the code....

Comment: @walimbeakshay show content for content_add_new_member.xml